# How to add parameter URL while keep old param?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using this for my page with pagination. But when I change page all of the old params I set removed.

```html
<li class="page-item"  th:unless="${page.number == i}"><a class="page-link" th:text="${i+1}"
   th:href="${'?'+('&page='+i)
  +(#request.getParameter('size')==null?'':('&size='+#request.getParameter('size')))
  +(#request.getParameter('sortByPrice')==null?'':('&sortByPrice='+#request.getParameter('sortByPrice')))
    }"></a>
</li>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

The current page1 reads the parameters `size` and `sortByPrice` from request object which might have been coming on as URL query parameters or form elements. When you go to the next page these 2 parameters are not present on request object so the 2nd page2 is not getting them. On the current page1 as you read `size` and `sortByPrice` also write them on page1 as hidden form elements then page2 will see them. You can write them on the URL to be clicked to go to page2.

Comment: In Spring MVC you may have a custom way to add a hidden field. Here is a generic way - a hidden field is like <input type="hidden" id="1" name="size" value=<%= request.getParameter("size") %>>. You need to update the 'value' field. I wrote basic JSP code but you would do differently in Spring MVC.